# How to build react native app on windows

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to build app in React Native using Windows instead of linux ?
I am a really beginner. On the official website ReatNative we can read:

> Assuming that you have Node installed, you can use npm to install the
>   create-react-native-app command line utility:
>
> npm install -g create-react-native-app Then run the following commands
>   to create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":
>
> create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
>
> cd AwesomeProject npm start

But how to do that on windows ? 
There is no information about that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page - [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

> Please note that you have to select **Building Projects with Native Code** Tab. Then you can select **Windows** and **Android**

Comment: but why I need to choose iOs or Android ? I thought react is 1 write for 2 platforms

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can only develop react native app for Android. Then if you want to build apps for iOS you need a IDE called Xcode. And Xcode is only available on mac OS. Other way to build apps for iOS is creating a mac OS virtual machine that runs on Windows. your pc / laptop must have enough computing power to run it. I think 8GB RAM, and SSD and a Intel i5 7x series would be enough.

For installing Node.js and other tools you need for your development on Windows you have to use the `command prompt.` That is what you was asking for. I hope it helps you. Let me know if you have success.

Take a look here

[How to use the Windows command line](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm)

[Getting Started with React Native Development on Windows](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65)